# PHP can not __autoload classes

Tags: php, url-routing, autoload

I have index.php where i keep my __autoload() function that loads classes from a lib folder.

```
 function __autoload($class) {
      if(file_exists(LIBS . $class .".php")){
           require LIBS . $class .".php";
      }
 }
```

I have a Dashboard class

```
 class Dashboard extends Controller {
      public function __construct(){
           Auth::handleLogin();
      }
 }
```

Using sudo apt-get install php5 and apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04 i am not able to autoload that Auth, what could possibly go wrong? It works on my other computer which uses a Bitnami XAMPP server.

This is the error i get:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Auth' not found in /var/www/app/controllers/dashboard.php on line 6
```

Where the Auth::handleLogin(); is being called.

Comment: `var_dump(LIBS . $class .".php", getcwd());`

Comment: nothing happens.. if i die("enters the function") it enters the function..

Comment: Where did you put it? `var_dump` in this case **SHOULD** output 2 values. If it doesn't - you've made something wrong.

Comment: string(38) "/var/www/rcs/app/backend/libs/Auth.php"
string(24) "/var/www/rcs/app/backend"

Fatal error: Class 'Auth' not found in /var/www/rcs/app/backend/app/controllers/dashboard.php on line 6

Comment: So? Does `/var/www/rcs/app/backend/libs/Auth.php` file exist? Don't forget that it should follow the letter capitalization as well.

Comment: lol, it appears that is case sensitive, but why, on the bitnami xampp server it doesn't matter if it is spelled with Auth.php or auth.php ..

Comment: lol zerkms, how could you possibly ask me if that file exist???????

Comment: "how could you possibly ask me if that file exist" --- I'm not sure I understand what you mean :-S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48206/discussion-between-sirbu-nicolae-cezar-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're experiencing that because in linux the filesystem paths are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

i have linux mint 16 and i use this with namespaces when i do object declaration 
and it is work perfect

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    $class = str_replace("\\", "/", $class);

    include $class . '.php';

});
```

in index file

```
require_once 'autoload.php';

$db = new DBWork\DBWork('localhost', 'northwind', 'root', '123');
```